# How to auto enroll patients in care plan?

Tags: hl7-fhir

I am new to FHIR and its various implementations. I am trying to make the fhir-net-api WebApi project work to my needs. I would like to develop workflow where:

1. An organization or an individual (family member or patient) would
   show an intent to enroll patient into a predefined care plan
   template.
2. Care plan template will consist of scheduled activities of various    kind (reading articles, taking questionnaires, attending
   meetings,    taking vitals).
3. Intent request would contain set of conditions the patient has    (CHF,COPD,DM) based on which a plan would be assigned to the
   patient.

I am struggling to figure out which FHIR entities I can use to communicate the intent and response of the intent action. I have looked at care plan profile. I also looked at the Workflow of FHIR but how to proceed is not clear. Please guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the definitions of the types of plans would use PlanDefinition - as that's patient and time-agnostic.  You could do a search for PlanDefinitions that cover the conditions of interest.

As for enrollment, that depends on what's meant by "enroll".  If it's just declared commitments of what the patient agrees to do, the system could create a CarePlan based on the PlanDefinition listing the specifics (and possibly tuning things based on what the patient actually agrees to do).  If you're looking for some sort of formal program enrollment request that might be accepted or rejected, then you'd need the patient to initiate a ServiceRequest (R4) or a ProcedureRequest or ReferralRequest (STU3), any of which could point to the relevant PlanDefinition.

Comment: Thanks Lloyd. "Enroll" means patient will get introduced to the program and activities to be done by him/her over the next few weeks. Patient will participate via an App or web portal and complete the scheduled activities. The enrolling organization or individual will track progress of this schedule.

Comment: Ok, that sounds like the creation of a CarePlan and the app then prompts them to support the execution of that plan.